# React useRef useImperativeHandle

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

In the login form bellow, I use, in my submit function, `document.getElementById()`. It works but I heard today it's not a grood pratice and I better use `useRef()` instead.

But after some research, `useRef()` can't work with custom components, like my `<FormInput/>`. After some re-research, I heard about `forwardRef()` and `useImperativeHandle()`

It still works, but I'm perplexed, my code seems to be more complex and less manageable.

What's your opinion about this use case?

Thanks in advance

**INITIAL CODE**

```
function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()     

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    await dispatch(
      fetchOrUpdateLogin({
        email: document.getElementById('username').value,
        password: document.getElementById('password').value,
      })
    )
    navigate('/user')
  }

  return (
    <main className="main bg-dark">
      <section className="sign-in-content">
        <i className="fa fa-user-circle sign-in-icon"></i>
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            content="Username"
            type="text"
            idFor="username"
            prefill={USER.email}
          />
          <FormInput
            content="Password"
            type="password"
            idFor="password"
            prefill={USER.password}
          />
          <div className="input-remember">
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />
            <label htmlFor="remember-me">Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <Button type="submit" content="Sign In" classStyle="sign-in-button" />
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}

function FormInput({ content, type, idFor, prefill }) {
  return (
    <div className="input-wrapper">
      <label htmlFor={idFor}>{content}</label>
      <input type={type} id={idFor} autoComplete="off" defaultValue={prefill} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const emailValue = useRef(null)
  const passwordValue = useRef(null)

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    await dispatch(
      fetchOrUpdateLogin({
        email: emailValue.current.inputValue(),
        password: passwordValue.current.inputValue(),
      })
    )
    navigate('/user')
  }

  return (
    <main className="main bg-dark">
      <section className="sign-in-content">
        <i className="fa fa-user-circle sign-in-icon"></i>
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            content="Username"
            type="text"
            idFor="username"
            prefill={USER.email}
            ref={emailValue}
          />
          <FormInput
            content="Password"
            type="password"
            idFor="password"
            prefill={USER.password}
            ref={passwordValue}
          />
          <div className="input-remember">
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />
            <label htmlFor="remember-me">Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <Button type="submit" content="Sign In" classStyle="sign-in-button" />
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}
const FormInput = ({ content, type, idFor, prefill }, ref) => {
  const valueRef = useRef(null)

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    inputValue() {
      return valueRef.current.value
    },
  }))
  return (
    <div className="input-wrapper">
      <label htmlFor={idFor}>{content}</label>
      <input
        ref={valueRef}
        type={type}
        id={idFor}
        autoComplete="off"
        defaultValue={prefill}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default forwardRef(FormInput)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cemil mentions, using state would be the more common solution to this. But if you need to use refs for something like this, you only need forwardRef, not useImperativeHandle:

```
const FormInput = ({ content, type, idFor, prefill }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className="input-wrapper">
      <label htmlFor={idFor}>{content}</label>
      <input
        ref={ref}
        type={type}
        id={idFor}
        autoComplete="off"
        defaultValue={prefill}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default forwardRef(FormInput)

// in Login:
fetchOrUpdateLogin({
  email: emailValue.current.value,
  password: passwordValue.current.value
})
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas and thank you. Indeed, I must have misinterpreted my sources, it works perfectly with forwardRef only.

As Cemil says, state is a good option. I'm still happy to have learned how to work with useRef and useImperativeHandle hooks, even if last one should not be found very often

Comment: In any case, are you ok with the statement that document.getElementById and other selectors are not recommended?

Comment: Yeah, the standard way in react to get access to the underlying dom elements is with refs. This helps to increase encapsulation and reduce coupling. The FormInput component is in charge of its part of the dom, and thus knows exactly which element it wants to expose. If you edit FormInput to change the id, the ref approach will still work, but the selector approach will break until you rewrite the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to ask this. Why don't you try a state based approach rather than using refs? I think it would be a better practice. That's how you can do.

1. Create a state variable inside of  component like

   `const [value, setValue] = useState();`
2. Give your value and setValue function to your input as

   `<input {...rest} value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />`
3. Whenever the value changes, pass it to your parent component so that your  component will run itself as a modular component and you will give just one job to your input component. You can do like this. Pass a prop to your input component like onChange which is a function:

   `useEffect(() => { props.onChange(value)}, [value])`
4. Save them in your parent component's state.
5. Use it from the state variables instead of taking the values from the ref.

I wrote it like this because you're using React and you should also use your  components based on their re-rendering. It would be a better use-case

Comment: Hello, and thank you. I tried this, simply because I was watching a video about all react hook explained. When I discovered useRef and he says "document.getElementById is not a good practice, I didn't think about anything else and try it, stupidly :) But I'll study your solution. Maybe hooks like useImperativeHandle are very very specific use cases. Good to know, but not to implement everywhere.